# How to reference current SKScene from the AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKScene that has a pause method. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    pauseLevel()
}
```

However, I don't know how to get a reference to my SKScene from the AppDelegate.

I tried using

```
 application.inputView
```

However, that is an UIView. How can I get an SKScene?

**EDIT**

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.17, green:0.24, blue:0.31, alpha:1.0)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(runPause), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}
```

would that be sufficient and effective at removing the observer every time?

Comment: no, it will only remove it when the scene is deleted from memory. if your scene stays in memory but is off of the current view,  the observer will still exist.  I do not know how your game is designed,  You have at least protected yourself from when the scene is removed from memory, so your app will not crash on exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would scrap your way of thinking.  in iOS, notifications get sent for when application events happen.  In your case, the notification is called `UIApplicationWillTerminate`

What you want to do is hook into this notification in your Scene class,  I would recommend in the `didMove(to:)` method.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pauseLevel), name: .UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
```

Now when you do this, you need to remember to remove the observer
 when you are removing the scene, so you want to use the code:

```
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

At moments the scene is removed.  I would recommend at the least putting it in the `deinit`

Now in Swift 4, things change a little bit.  You need to add `@objc` to your pauseLevel function so that it can be exposed to objective c libraries.